# How do I install GCJ on OSX

Tags: macos, java, compile, gcc

I've looked at the [gcj page](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/docs.html) and though there's downloads links they're only for downloading gcc, and with the apple version of gcc there is no gcj included:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
$ gcj
zsh: command not found: gcj
```

or with the homebrew-installed gcc 4.9:

```
➜  ~  gcc-4.9 --version
gcc-4.9 (GCC) 4.9.0 20140302 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
➜  ~  gcj
zsh: command not found: gcj
```

and searching for it in the gcc help doesn't work:

```
➜  ~  gcc --help|grep -i gcj
➜  ~  gcc --help|grep -i java
➜  ~  gcc-4.9 --help|grep -i java 
➜  ~  gcc-4.9 --help|grep -i gcj
```

I've seen [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/80235/how-can-i-install-gcj-on-linux) about how to install it on Linux, and I was hoping there'd be a homebrew formula, bit no such luck.

Any ideas on how to install GCJ on OSX?

Comment: That's not "the Apple version of GCC".  That's [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), a _completely different compiler_ which handles the C, C++, Objective C, and Objective C++ languages.  No Java.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. The gcc that I installed with homebrew *is* actually gcc though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
brew install gcc --with-java
```

it will appear as `/usr/local/bin/gcj-5` (for example)

Comment: it works for me on Mac OS Sierra

Comment: Doesn't work anymore: "Error: invalid option: --with-java" Maybe Homebrew changed the command line interface. Or maybe it's simply because GCJ is basically dead.